# Visual Studio web project has IIS configuration warnings

Tags: visual-studio, iis, configuration, warnings, vs-web-application-project

One of the web application projects in my Visual Studio solution has a blue exclamation mark icon on it and the tool tip shows

> The Web project <Project.Name.Here> has IIS configuration warnings

I can't see anything in the project `Properties` pages, or in the `web.config` file. It started yesterday, and I assumed restarting Visual Studio and reloading the project may get rid of the warning, but it has not.

What is this and how do I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try right clicking the solution in the 'Solution Explorer', the option 'Resolve Errors' should be available.

[image]

Selecting this should show you the message behind the icon you're seeing on the project.  For me, this was:

> ASP.NET 4.0 has not been registered on the Web server.  You need to manually configure your Web server for ASP.NET 4.0 in order for your site to run correctly.

If this is the message you're receiving, this [MS blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6/) may help you fix it.

**Update**

Note that once you've selected this option, the IDE assumes you've resolved the errors and removes the icon and menu option (!).  So make sure you read it or restart VS to see it again.

Comment: Thank you. Looks promising but I will check with the rest of my team if we can install that hotfix. (We have to install all updates together). Then I'll feed back on here if it worked and mark this as the answer.